# Will this be my final Riley Riddle?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, poetry, affix-riddle

This won't be my final one, although the riddle suggests otherwise...

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My prefix might be two, but dominatės an aching storm; 
>  Though rid the kind of regulär a pirate may infôrm.*
>
> *My suffix might set off, but to be hönest, is reversed, 
>  As it might be éntirely its own way quite hèådfirst.*
>
> *My infix is a link you might demañd not in a chain, 
>  But rather only once to thrice in what your šight may gain.*
>
> *A pale queen would know my name; her voice would be on sāle! 
>  Ironic, for sō frēqùęntły, some deserts have my trail.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

Much as I've left this riddle for you, 
 The answer has left itself for you, too.

---

Partial answers can be posted :)

**Hint 1:**

> Pirates say, "Arrrr!" 
>  You're on your way after you have set off. 
>  And this and that and so much to think about! 
>  This riddle seemed so deserted.

**Hint 2:**

> The word "stomach" sounds like "storm aching" but without the r (and ing). Stomachs also have "abdominals" which sounds like "ab dominating".

---

Seems like finding out what the symbols might mean is a bit too difficult, so whoever finds that out will earn a $100$ rep bounty.. but you might have a chance at it, because I will say one thing:

> So frequently $\to$ frost queen... if on**ly**...

Comment: Are the weird things in characters important?

Comment: @u_ndefined yes, they are. They sort of hint out to something. If you don't understand one part, I can give a hint for that particular "weird thing".

Comment: I'm tempted to post an answer... "No."

Comment: @jafe hahah, the answer would make sense once you get it. You are staring at more clues than you think :P

Answer (score 1):

Partial (infix):

> 'w'? link not in chain: URL, once to thrice: "www."

Comment: That was a good attempt, but unfortunately incorrect. Every affix is a word... well, maybe not the prefix (it all depends on how you say it, really), but that's it. In fact, the prefix is a well-known one; if you search "define [prefix]", Google will tell you that it *is* a prefix :P

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> DIACRITIC !

Or perhaps you are about to

> "die a critic" meaning this is one of your final Riley riddles. I hope not, although you were last seen a month ago... If it was due to foul play, perhaps they said "die, 'ya critic!"

This obviously explains all of the

> strewn about diacritic marks

But some additional insight:

My prefix might be two, but dominatės an aching storm;
Though rid the kind of regulär a pirate may infôrm.

> Your prefix is "DI", a prefix meaning 'two'. We note that the unique letters in you, DIACRT, dominate 'aching storm' as they all appear.  Not sure about the pirate bit, but it may explain how to remove the extra letters.

My suffix might set off, but to be hönest, is reversed,
As it might be éntirely its own way quite hèådfirst.

> Your suffix is "CRITIC", which can set someone off (make them upset), but in reverse, a headfirst critic may be all alone in their views, not shared by the majority.

My infix is a link you might demañd not in a chain,
But rather only once to thrice in what your šight may gain.

> Your infix is "A", a link (hyperlink HTML code, or anchor), which is not a link in a chain but a link you click a few times to visit a new page or activate a function.

A pale queen would know my name; her voice would be on sāle!
Ironic, for sō frēqùęntły,

> I was lost on a tangent for awhile with Elsa from Frozen, but the actual answer made me laugh. "Pale Queen" clues a frozen, icy queen, as does 'frequently' which sounds like "frozen queen". Here, the queen is actually the White Witch in Narnia, famous for her winter appearance, and pale also clueing white. She was voiced ("voice" clue) by Tilda Swinton in the 2005 movie.  Tilda likely is no stranger to jokes about her name sounding like 'tilde', a common diacritic.

some deserts have my trail.

> The two largest deserts on earth are the Antarctic and Arctic, which share the tail, or end, of DIACRITIC (TIC)!